# MS Coded UI Tests Search Properties not acquiring new Xaml AutomationID

Tags: xaml, coded-ui-tests

I've created a simple MS Coded UI test and associated WPF application to try to understand AutomationIDs. First, I assign an AutomationID to the the Xaml code of a textBox. Then, I record typing into the textBox and create an associated UIMap function. Initially, in the Search Properties for the textBox, the AutomationID is correct. However, if I change the xaml AutomationID, the Search Properties will not pick up the new AutomationID? Here is my code and screen shots:

'Xaml Code: For the TextBox, I changed the AutoamtionId from "TextBoxAutoID01" to "TextBoxAutoID07"

```
<Grid>
    <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" Content="CheckBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="176,254,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="True"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="176,147,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" AutomationProperties.AutomationId="TextBoxAutoID07"/>

</Grid>`
```

In the TextBox UIMap Search Properties, the AutomationID is still the original "TextBoxAutoID01"

[image]

And the UIMap.design.cs Code reflects that the new AutomationID has not been updated:

```
 public WpfEdit UITextBoxAutoID01Edit
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUITextBoxAutoID01Edit == null))
            {
                this.mUITextBoxAutoID01Edit = new WpfEdit(this);
                #region Search Criteria
                this.mUITextBoxAutoID01Edit.SearchProperties[WpfEdit.PropertyNames.AutomationId] = "TextBoxAutoID01";
                this.mUITextBoxAutoID01Edit.WindowTitles.Add("MainWindow");
                #endregion
            }
            return this.mUITextBoxAutoID01Edit;
        }
    }
```

So at this point, the only way to make the Search Properties update is deleting the control for the UIMap and recording again.

Any insight on how to update a new xaml AutomationID with out re-recording the UIMap would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The Coded UI test and the WPF application are separate and independant. Changing one will not cause a change in the other. If you change the WPF application and generate new application-ids then you will need to manually change the Coded UI test to match.

There is no need to delete any controls, and no need to re-record the test or a part of it. Just alter the value of the search property -- note that the window is titled "Edit search properties". Just click in the "Value" field of the relevant property and change the value.

Comment: Great, thank you! I guess my only concern is when I start testing WPF applications written by others. Here, if a developer changes the AutomationID, then the corresponding one will have to manually be changed in the CUIT. This of course is okay with good communication but not ideal. I guess at the very least, changing an AutomationID will break the test code and therefore give a heads-up that it has changed.

Comment: @kme If you expect the AutomationID to change frequently then find some other properties of the control, things that will not change. Delete the AutomationID in the "Edit search properties" window and add the other properties.